# Using NSNotifier to call a method when app is in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am using the NSNotifier to create an Alarm Clock that calls a method when the time set is reached. I can get this to work successfully when the App is in the foreground. But when in the background, I can only get a notification to be presented.

Is it possible to call a method using the NSNotifier, when the app is in the background? If so how do I accomplish this?

Here is my code so far:-

**appdelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ProcessDidComplete:) name:@"ProcessDidComplete" object:nil];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ProcessDidComplete" object:nil];
}

- (void) ProcessDidComplete:(NSNotification *)pNotification
{
    NSString *processData;
    processData = @"Processing Data";
}
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
-(void)addLocalNotification
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
    notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, `-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` only gets called when the application is in the foreground.

See documentation for [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:) and [handling local and remote notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4).